# Best library or method to plot data from wireless connected Arduino, asynchronously

Tags: c#, java, lua, visualization, arduino

Essentially, I have an Arduino with more than 10 sensors on board that will be gathering and logging time-stamped data while in flight. It will also be serializing and sending this data wirelessly to a laptop on the ground.

The laptop needs to have software that can read the wireless serial data, parse its contents, determine which sensor the data is coming from, and plot the data on a graph (line or bar depending on the data). The read and un-serialize part shouldn't be a problem. What I am looking for is the best/easiest library or method for creating 2D graphs of this data as it comes in, shift the graph over (if necessary), and draw the graph points relative to the accompanying time stamps.

This software will basically function as a dashboard or control panel for the project. Many graphs will need to be added to this window to handle each of the sensors that currently exist, and that may exist in the future.

The closest things I could find based on this topic are below.

- *[Realtime Plot of Arduino Serial Data Using Python](http://www.blendedtechnologies.com/realtime-plot-of-arduino-serial-data-using-python)*
- Arduino example *[Graph](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Graph)* (how to send a byte of data from the Arduino to a personal computer and graph the result)

Are there any data visualization, graphing/plotting, or graphics libraries that would be best suited to tackle a project such as this?

Any programming language is fine.

Comment: What do you need to do with those graphs? Just plot them on the screen? You need to print them on paper, for example?

Comment: Just plot them on screen. I will be dumping the data to a CSV file for more thorough analysis later.

Comment: Assuming you wish this plotting to take place in a browser?  If so, then you have to choose between Flash/Silverlight, or some HTML approach that doesn't require those plugins.  This I think is more of a plotting question and not an Arduino question per se, meaning, if you post in an area having to do with that, you'll get more advice I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Processing](http://processing.org)

And these books:
http://processing.org/learning/books/

Comment: +1, it looks like the best option. It even has a serial port lib: http://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using gnuplot is an option like they do [here](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/gnuplotStreaming.html)